# How do I find out where the Mercurial hook file is being called from?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

On the project I am working on there is a standard pre-commit hook for mercurial that looks something like this:

```
python:hookhgext.messagevalidation.checkCommitMessage
```

I would like to find out where the python script is located so I can create my own hook script that also calls this.

How would I either find the location of this file or also call this hook from a python script?

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to [docs](https://book.mercurial-scm.org/read/hook.html#telling-mercurial-to-use-an-in-process-hook)

> The value of the hook must start with the text “python:”, and continue
>   with the fully-qualified name of a callable object to use as the
>   hook's value.
>   …
>   So long as you have the module name and PYTHONPATH right, it should
>   “just work”

I.e. in your case Mercurial imports `hookhgext.messagevalidation` (from any possible for import location) and call `checkCommitMessage` from it.

I know nothing about Python, but *for me* `hookhgext.messagevalidation` is "messagevalidation" *something* inside "hookhgext.py", and "hookhgext" is the usual installed python-module in it's (installed modules) default location(s)